How to find where my memory leak is in Angular 17 SSR?
I've got a memory leak in my production environment with Angular SSR. Essentially, every time a page is refreshed, it leaks.
I see HTMLBaseElement still being referenced.

And I see R3Injector still being referenced.

I've unsubscribed all the observables and I've updated zone as per angular ssr issue, but I still see an increase in memory usage.
What is interesting, is that I see CSS being in memory and I don't see that making much sense.

Any ideas of what I should be trying?
Package.json dependencies are:
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.0.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^17.3.10",
    "@angular/common": "^17.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "^17.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^17.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "^17.0.2",
    "@angular/ssr": "^17.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^16.0.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^17.0.1",
    "@ngrx/store": "^17.0.1",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^17.0.1",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^3.1.0",
    "@types/intercom-web": "^2.8.24",
    "angular-google-tag-manager": "^1.9.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "http-proxy": "^1.18.1",
    "jquery": "^3.7.1",
    "luxon": "^3.4.3",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^13.1.1",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^17.1.0",
    "ngx-slick-carousel": "^17.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.8"
  },


If your memory consumption increases with the page refresh it's not memory leak of Angular. When you refresh the page JS is "killed". You may have some plugins that keep references. Also, the console itself can hold some references and cause "leaks". Try incognito mode. Make sure you don't have any plugins running. Memory leaks are happening throughout JS lifecycle. When you refresh – the cycle ends. Whatever happens after that is on your browser

Based on your screenshot, I don't have enough information to tell you which one is leaking but I can give you a strategy to find the culprit, not the fastest one but usually the most guaranteed one.
Try a divide and conquer approach:

Pages: Remove one by one page in your route, check if the leak still happened. If the leak stopped, you found the page that cause leak, now you can lower the scope to that page only
Components: Remove one by one in that page, repeated until you found the component.
Inside the component, assuming you are using standalone, check all the pipe, service, or other component that you are importing, remove until the leak stop. Check the one that cause the leak and fix it.

Usually need to find out if you are using setTimeout, setInterval or timer of rxjs, also check for cycle import(usually you will get noticed by your IDE), check if you do any dom manipulation inside ngOnChanges or ngDoCheck, these two life cycle run a lot and can cause serious problem if you don't check carefully.
My approach will take you a lot of time but if you have no other choice, just try it. If you have a working version without leaking before this version. You can reduce the scope to read quicker based on what you added from the working version until this version.

There can be many reasons for memory leak in angular, check for below mentioned things in code to find memory leaks

A subject/Behavior Subject/Observable is subscribed but not unsubscribed on ngOnDestroy in any component.
Subject/Behavior Subject/Observable is being subscribed multiple times(maybe in ngOnChanges or anything like that).


Both are already checked, nothing of sorts is happening.

Are there any setTimeouts or setIntervals running in code without proper termination of them? Any network connections like SSE or Web socket with the logic can also cause trouble, so check for that also.

Just a suggestion:
Basic checks include but not limited to:

Every ngFor / @for should have a 'trackBy'
Every Behavior Subject / Subscription should be unsubscribed either using
rxjs operators or in ng on destroy
any event listeners using renderer2 should be destroyed.
change detection strategy - if using push, use it wisely.
Any timers / setintervals / setTimeouts, etc should be cleared out.
if using JSON.stringify() or JSON.parse() make sure to use try-catch blocks.
Any API retries, make sure to have a catchError block and keep the retries count to either 5 or max 10 nothing more. Even 10 is too high

